# How to make protoc generated python stub file to include package name in import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, grpc, protoc

I use the protoc tool, from grpc-tools package (ver. 1.43.0) with python 3.8.10 to generate the data types and client and server stubs for my proto3 service.  The generated file containing the stubs (ending in '_grpc.py') imports the generated file containing the message data types using an import statement with no package name: 'import <my_service_name>_pb2.py'.  If I understand correctly, in order for this import to work properly in python 3 when the generated code is being included in a package, this import needs to include the name of the package containing it: 'from <my_containing_package> import <my_service_name>_pb2.py'.  Is there a way to make protoc generate this import with the package name I require?

P.S. I'm currently using sed to post edit the generated file to add the package name, so only interested, here, in a way to make protoc generate the correct form for python 3 in the first place.

Comment: Coincidentally I just (re-)bumped into the same problem.  (Have bumped into it before...)

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR; use https://github.com/cpcloud/protoletariat.

From that tool, you can follow the discussion on the [protocolbuffers issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1491),
which basically clarifies that the intended use is to pump all your stubs
in a flat source directory.

Answer (score 0):

The official recommendation is to add the Python Proto Package folder to the Path ( September 2023 )

You can do this with the code below in __init__.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

https://github.com/dydxprotocol/v4-chain/pull/215